# Run time Complex XML to XML transformation using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT. My test case is as follows:

1. My source XML is not in XML file but W3C Document of JDOM Document object which come as parameter.
2. I need to convert the given source XML into other XML structure designed by end user at run time.
3. I also need to manipulate values of text nodes in the source XML document depending on the inputs from end user.
   Is XSLT recommended for such complex transformation?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/dom/DOMSource.html allows you to use a W3C DOM Node as the input to an XSLT Transformer. Saxon is also known to support JDOM documents http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/thirdparty.html. Whether your requirements "designed by the end user at run time/depending on the inputs from the end user" can be met by XSLT I can't tell from that description, you would need to explain in more detail what kind of transformation you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Regarding run time user dependent inputs, the user  creates or generates nodes on UI from input XML. The user then creates destination nodes for the other XML structure desired as output. The user maps the attributes of these nodes to the one at destination side. The nodes on both side are represented in tabular format. The rows of the table represent attribute. The user draws lines and maps them with desired attributes on destination side. The user may add more nodes at run time which are not present in original XML and map them to the one at destination.

Comment: Hope my description mentioned above helps us in getting answers. Thanks for the prompt reply.